# Whats wrong with my jquery syntax?

Tags: jquery, html

I've got this navigation on my website that is being loaded with a php include and i've had to change my code a bit to account for this by running my script after the document is loaded.

also, If they visit the site through a link other than index.php the right link won't be active so I have to find & set the correct active link based on the url

So here is the code i've came up with so far, but it's not working and i'm getting a syntax error.

```
$(document).ready($("nav ul li a").href == window.location.pathname {
 $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Any suggestions?

Solution -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("nav ul li a").each(function(){
        var myLinkHref = $(this).attr('href');
        myURLPath = window.location.href;
        if ( myLinkHref == myURLPath ){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Note: while on your index page window.location.href usually returns http://www.example.com/ not http://www.example.com/index.php so make sure your home link is the full path excluding index.php so it returns true.

Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Hit F12, what is the syntax error?

Comment: Why is there a `{` after `pathname`?

Comment: $(document).ready( if($("nav ul li a").attr("href") == window.location.pathname) {
 $(this).addClass("active");}
});

Comment: Akshay Chawla - your code didn't work, gave me unexpected token errors

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are assigning a function to a function. `$(document).ready()` is a wrapper to your scripts in after the page has loaded. You might want something more like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //do your things here;
});
```

Though I cannot determine what exactly it is you are trying to do. `window.location.pathname` is a read only property, but you give it an object with a statement inside. Maybe

`$("nav ul li a").addClass("active");`

is closer to what you mean, but that is going to add the `active` class to every link in the list of links on the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("nav ul li a").each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ( href == window.location.pathname ){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Explain:
After load the entire document, do a loop in each "a element" inside "nav ul li". Get the HREF and compare. If equal, add "active" class.

I hop it helps

Comment: I tried your code, didn't work. could this be an issue with the include_once php?

Comment: Hi @junkie-monkie, theres another thing in your code wich do not make it works. Look the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2sxdoyq9/4/ In this fiddle I just replace window.location.pathname to my_path variable. And it works. In the fiddle theres no '$(window).load(function()' because  fiddle loads like that. Theres some error in your console?

Comment: Thanks, i was able to figure out the solution with the help of your fiddle.

Comment: @junkie-monkie Great! Glad it helped.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $( 'nav ul li a' ).each(function( ) {
          if($(this).attr('href') == window.location.pathname) {
              $(this).addClass("active");
          }
     });
});
```

Your syntax for the document ready function is not correct. You need write document ready as above.

You need to loop through all your menu items to check if your url matches the link & add active class to the matching item.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan. I have just added my inputs to the answer.